# Optimization of MySQL query with LIMIT

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this setup;

tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoice` (
    `invoice_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `offer_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `currency_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `insert_date_invoice` DATE NOT NULL,    
    `propagation_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`invoice_id`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE INDEX `propagation_id` (`propagation_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_invoice_offer` (`offer_id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `insert_date_invoice` (`insert_date_invoice`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `FK_invoice_currency` (`currency_id`) USING BTREE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_invoice_currency` FOREIGN KEY (`currency_id`) REFERENCES `db_frost`.`currency` (`currency_id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_invoice_offer` FOREIGN KEY (`offer_id`) REFERENCES `db_frost`.`offer` (`offer_id`) ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;

CREATE TABLE `currency` (
    `currency_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `currency` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb3_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`currency_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb3_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=1
;
```

When running this those two queries I get different performances, described with explain command results. Only difference is that I selected one more field from currency table. Currency table has 3 entries (3 rows).

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, currency.currency_id
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN currency ON (currency.currency_id = invoice.currency_id) 
ORDER BY invoice.invoice_id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | invoice | \N | index | FK_invoice_currency | PRIMARY | 8 | \N | **30** | 100.00 | \N |
| 1 | SIMPLE | currency | \N | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | db_frost.invoice.currency_id | 1 | 100.00 | Using index |

EXPLAIN ANALYZE result:

```
-> Limit: 30 row(s)  (cost=16867 rows=30) (actual time=0.0448..0.0555 rows=30 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=16867 rows=30) (actual time=0.0439..0.0532 rows=30 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on invoice using PRIMARY  (cost=0.14 rows=30) (actual time=0.0346..0.0377 rows=30 loops=1)
        -> Single-row covering index lookup on currency using PRIMARY (currency_id=invoice.currency_id)  (cost=0.25 rows=1) (actual time=355e-6..375e-6 rows=1 loops=30)
```

EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON result:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "30667.05"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "invoice",
            "access_type": "index",
            "possible_keys": [
              "FK_invoice_currency"
            ],
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "invoice_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "8",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 30,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 67454,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "312.75",
              "eval_cost": "6745.40",
              "prefix_cost": "7058.15",
              "data_read_per_join": "477M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "invoice_id",
              "currency_id"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "currency",
            "access_type": "eq_ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "key": "PRIMARY",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "currency_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "db_frost.invoice.currency_id"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 67454,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "16863.50",
              "eval_cost": "6745.40",
              "prefix_cost": "30667.05",
              "data_read_per_join": "26M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "currency_id"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Second query:

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, currency.currency_id, **currency.currency**
FROM invoice
INNER JOIN currency ON (currency.currency_id = invoice.currency_id) 
ORDER BY invoice.invoice_id DESC
LIMIT 30
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | invoice | \N | index | FK_invoice_currency | FK_invoice_currency | 4 | \N | **67759** | 100.00 | Using index Using temporary Using filesort |
| 1 | SIMPLE | currency | \N | ALL | PRIMARY | \N | \N | \N | 3 | 33.33 | Using where; Using join buffer (hash join) |

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE result:
-> Limit: 30 row(s)  (actual time=43.8..43.8 rows=30 loops=1)
    -> Sort: invoice.invoice_id, limit input to 30 row(s) per chunk  (actual time=43.8..43.8 rows=30 loops=1)
        -> Stream results  (cost=27295 rows=67454) (actual time=19.6..38.2 rows=69067 loops=1)
            -> Inner hash join (currency.currency_id = invoice.currency_id)  (cost=27295 rows=67454) (actual time=19.6..30 rows=69067 loops=1)
                -> Table scan on currency  (cost=16.6e-6 rows=3) (actual time=0.0138..0.0169 rows=3 loops=1)
                -> Hash
                    -> Covering index scan on invoice using FK_invoice_currency  (cost=7058 rows=67454) (actual time=0.0367..11.5 rows=69067 loops=1)
```

EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON result:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "27295.37"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "invoice",
            "access_type": "index",
            "possible_keys": [
              "FK_invoice_currency"
            ],
            "key": "FK_invoice_currency",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "currency_id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 67454,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 67454,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "312.75",
              "eval_cost": "6745.40",
              "prefix_cost": "7058.15",
              "data_read_per_join": "477M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "invoice_id",
              "currency_id"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "currency",
            "access_type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": [
              "PRIMARY"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 3,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 67454,
            "filtered": "33.33",
            "using_join_buffer": "hash join",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1.02",
              "eval_cost": "6745.40",
              "prefix_cost": "27295.37",
              "data_read_per_join": "26M"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "currency_id",
              "currency"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`db_frost`.`currency`.`currency_id` = `db_frost`.`invoice`.`currency_id`)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1st query does not need in `currency` table body access. Rather than 2nd query.

Comment: What version are you using? Query `SELECT VERSION();`.

Comment: Originally I saw the issue on old MySQL version 5.1.7.
Then I tested it on my machine on MariaDB version 10.11.2.
Then I spun another MySQL server version 8.2.0. There I created new database, new tables, strip all (for this issue) unnecessary columns and inserted data from original tables. Everywhere I same problem appeared. As far as I can see it does not look related to MySQL version. Or, maybe I am missing something.

Comment: The Optimizer has rarely taken adequate consideration of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT.  You seem to have found an excellent example of such.  user1191247  shows two workarounds.

Comment: If you can provide a test case on 8.0, please file a bug report with those two queries -- bugs.mysql.com .   I would like them to fix it.l

Comment: If available, provide EXPLAIN ANALYZE and EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON. (Neither of these was available in 5.1.)

Comment: @RickJames I updated my question with data you requested. I will file a bug report, probably not today since it's a bit late right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your current join to a correlated subquery in the SELECT list or move the main query to a subquery and then join to the currency table:

```
SELECT invoice.invoice_id, currency.currency_id,
    (SELECT currency FROM currency WHERE currency_id = invoice.currency_id) AS currency
FROM invoice
ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
LIMIT 30;
```

or:

```
SELECT i.*, c.currency
FROM (
    SELECT invoice_id, currency_id
    FROM invoice
    ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
    LIMIT 30
) i
INNER JOIN currency c ON c.currency_id = i.currency_id;
```

Comment: Yes, this worked. Only issue is that this is part of far more complex query that joins 10 tables and have several where clauses (they are dynamic clauses) and I am not sure how will it scale. I will wait to see if someone will come with some, to say, more scalable solution and if not I will mark this as solution. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: I assumed this was with a very old MySQL version, as you would get a different plan from modern versions. To have any chance of getting a more relevant answer you will need to update your question with full details of your query. Did you make sure the index statistics were up to date before rerunning your tests in later versions?

Comment: Yes I did optimization of the tables. I will work with your idea to make full query performant as it could be.